# Importing pysftp issue

Tags: python, azure, azure-pipelines, pysftp

I am facing this error every time I try to import `pysftp` in my training.py in the ml.azure.com pipelines. I am using Conda to create the environment for the workspace.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "start_training.py", line 18, in <module>
    import pysftp
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_8b4da5162aa2d3fe6990b8afc7945879/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pysftp/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    import paramiko
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_8b4da5162aa2d3fe6990b8afc7945879/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from paramiko.transport import SecurityOptions, Transport
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_8b4da5162aa2d3fe6990b8afc7945879/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 89, in <module>
    from paramiko.dsskey import DSSKey
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_8b4da5162aa2d3fe6990b8afc7945879/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/dsskey.py", line 37, in <module>
    from paramiko.pkey import PKey
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_8b4da5162aa2d3fe6990b8afc7945879/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/pkey.py", line 31, in <module>
    import bcrypt
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_8b4da5162aa2d3fe6990b8afc7945879/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bcrypt/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from . import _bcrypt  # type: ignore
ImportError: libffi.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What I **tried** and **failed**:

I also tried to import the older version of `pysftp` which doesn't have dependency on `libffi.so`,
I tried with several versions of `pysftp`.

I tried installing the dependencies of `pysftp`.

I tried installing `paramiko` separately with current and older version.

I tried installing the `bcrypt` with current and older version.

I tried installing `libffi.so` with current and older version.

I tried creating new environments.

I tried by updating conda and pip also.

I tried to create simlink between `libffi.so.6` and `libffi.so.7` also.

So far, nothing works.

Help needed on this.

Comment: Please read the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info) of the ML tag.

Comment: Tried to check what installs libffi.so.7 ? Ie `yum provides */libffi.so.7` in centos ?

Comment: The os used on ml.azure.com for my subscription is:
NAME= **"Ubuntu"**
VERSION= **"18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"**
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic

Comment: Found the solution, had to move my os image to a higher version of ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04. This is the solution that Microsoft Customer support and me found by hit and trail.